# how to Achive this in visual studio (from visual vode extension)

Tags: code, visual-studio-2017

[so i want this feature(code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sHlh.png)

[to get to here(visual studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fXqp.png)

so i was wondering you can see in the first picture the first char of for if while(etc) has slight caligraphy in it? do anyone know how to do that in visual studio

Comment: Those are just fonts. You can change any fonts in Visual Studio from settings.

Comment: actually i just want the first characther to have that kiind of font. and in visual studio u cant change font for one spesific thing (operator, plain text,etc).

Answer (score 0):

The two images differ in font setting. To change font in Visual Studio,
open Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors. Go to Display Items
scroll menu, choose the required item of which font will be changed. For this
question, `if`, `else`, `when` are called Keywords. So, choose Keywords item,
then change the  font or color as your need. Here is the screenshot in VS 2017:

[image: change_fonts_for_keywords]

But at the time of this writing, Visual Studio does not support Italics
font by default. There may be some extension to change that. Follow these
threads to be aware whenever that feature will be available:

- [UserVoice: Editor support for italics fonts syntax highlighting](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2840449-editor-support-for-italics-fonts-syntax-highlighting)
- [Developer Community: code editor italic fonts?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/174399/code-editor-italic-fonts.html)

## Further readings

- [How to: Change fonts and colors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-the-editor)
- [Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/fonts-and-colors-environment-options-dialog-box)